# Is it possible in SQL Server IFilter to search pdf and get text?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, full-text-search, ifilter

I have adobe IFilter working with SQL SERVER 2012 to full-text search PDF files within the database. I'm curious if its possible to use that as well to get the text before and after the  search terms.

ex:
I'm searching for the work Adobe.
I want to some how get partial text before and after the word.

...maybe create a **Adobe** pdf to show the charts that...

I was trying to extract all the text and upload them to a separate table during the upload of the pdf but this caused a lot of performance issues as well as being unreliable.